# How to render a select box based on the values of another in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs

```
class Rent extends React.Component{

  changeModel(){
      var ele = document.getElementById('car_type').value;
      var val = document.getElementById('car_model');
      var hatch = "<option value = 'Indica'>Indica</option><option value='Swift'>Swift</option><option value = 'Logan'>Logan</option>";
      var sedan = "<option value = 'Indigo'>Indigo</option><option value='Xuv'>Xuv</option><option value = 'Accent'>Accent</option>";
      var van = "<option value = 'Omni'>Omni</option><option value='Vagon-R'>Vagon-R</option><option value = 'Bolero'>Bolero</option>";
      switch(ele){
        case 'hatchback':
              React.render(hatch,val);
              break;
        case 'sedan':
              React.render(sedan,val);
              break;
        case 'van':
              React.render(van,val);
              break;
      }

  }

    render(){
        return(
           <div id = "content">
                  <div id="content-header">

                  <div className="container-fluid">
                      <div className="widget-box">

                        <div className="widget-content nopadding">
                          <form action="#" method="get" className="form-horizontal">
                                    <div className="control-group">
                                      <label className="control-label">Car Type</label>
                                        <div className="controls" >
                                          <select id ="car_type" onChange = {this.changeModel}>
                                            <option value ="hatchback">Hatch Back</option>
                                            <option value ="van">Van</option>
                                            <option value ="sedan">Sedan</option>
                                          </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                      <div className="control-group">
                                        <label className="control-label">Car Model</label>
                                        <div className="controls ">
                                          <select id ="car_model" placeholder = "Select Car model">                
                                          </select>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                </form>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                                    </form>
                              </div>
                            </div>
            </div>
          </div>

         )
    }
}
```

This is my code I can't render my car_model select box based on the car_type select box.I have used reactJS render function to modify virtual DOM and also tried to modify actual DOM using `.innerHTML` function but none of them worked out.

Comment: you can use `event.target.value` instead of `getElementById` in `changeModel()` method, access the value by `event.target.value`.

Comment: in render fun, there is a mismatch of `</form>`, u closed `form` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
class Rent extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      catType: 'hatchback',
    }
 }

 changeModel(){
    var ele = document.getElementById('car_type').value;
    this.setState({catType: ele});      
 }

 _populateModels(){

   var hatch = [ <option value = 'Indica'>Indica</option>,
                <option value='Swift'>Swift</option>,
                <option value = 'Logan'>Logan</option>];
   var sedan = [ <option value = 'Indigo'>Indigo</option>,
                <option value='Xuv'>Xuv</option>,
                <option value = 'Accent'>Accent</option>];
   var van = [ <option value = 'Omni'>Omni</option>,
              <option value='Vagon-R'>Vagon-R</option>,
              <option value = 'Bolero'>Bolero</option>];

   switch(this.state.catType){
    case 'hatchback':
          return hatch;
    case 'sedan':
          return sedan;
    case 'van':
          return van;
  }
}

render(){
    return(
        <div id = "content">
            <div id="content-header">
              <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="widget-box">

                    <div className="widget-content nopadding">
                      <form action="#" method="get" className="form-horizontal">
                                <div className="control-group">
                                    <label className="control-label">Car Type</label>
                                    <div className="controls" >
                                      <select id ="car_type" onChange = {this.changeModel.bind(this)}>
                                        <option value ="hatchback">Hatch Back</option>
                                        <option value ="van">Van</option>
                                        <option value ="sedan">Sedan</option>
                                      </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                  <div className="control-group">
                                    <label className="control-label">Car Model</label>
                                    <div className="controls ">
                                      <select id ="car_model" placeholder = "Select Car model">
                                        {this._populateModels()}                
                                      </select>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     )
  }
}
```

`Jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/pyfnh7c0/

Comment: By giving this, facing the same problem

Comment: state value is not changing... changeModel() is not getting executed

Comment: did u bind the function `onChange = {this.changeModel.bind(this)}` check the `jsfiddle` use the same code, it will work.

Comment: yeh in jsfiddle its working, same code in my project,, but still facing the same prob ,,, actually the state is not changing... the model select box contains default hatchback value

Comment: put a `console.log(document.getElementById('car_type').value)` in `changeModal` method and check what the value it is printing.

Comment: i used the same code in my project it is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

No need of `DOM` element selection and appending dynamic content to it.

Why don't you use the power of `React` to maintain dynamic `select` boxes.

One pure `React` approach. Try something like this.

```js
class Rent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.cars = {
        hatchback : ['Indica', 'Swift', 'Logan'],
        sedan : ['Indigo', 'Xuv', 'Accent'],
        van : ['Omni', 'Vagon-R', 'Bolero'],
      }; //refactor your cars data into key values
      this.state = {
        currentDropdown: this.cars.hatchback //initially first selection 
      }
    }

    changeModel = (event) => {
      this.setState({ //changing state based on first selectbox value
        currentDropdown: this.cars[event.target.value]
      });
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
         <div>
          <label className = "control-label" > Car Type < /label>
          <select id ="car_type" onChange = {this.changeModel}>
            <option value ="hatchback">Hatch Back</option >
            <option value = "van" > Van < /option>
            <option value ="sedan">Sedan</option >
          </select>
          <label className="control-label">Car Model</label >
          <select id="car_model" placeholder = "Select Car model">
          {
            this.state.currentDropdown.map(item => {
              return <option key={item} value={item}>{item}</option>
            })          
          }
          </select>
         </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Rent /> , document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this` to your `onChange`.

```
<select id ="car_type" onChange = {this.changeModel.bind(this)}>
```

The reason for this is that the scope of the function changes when invoked from a different context, unless you explicitly bind the function to a certain this.

Let me know if you face any difficulties after this.

Comment: Binding the function explicitly also didn't worked out. Still i faced the same prob

Answer (score 0):

You should not return a string in react.render function.
so it should be like this otherwise:

```
const  Hatch  = () => (   <select> <option value = 'Indica'>Indica</option><option value='Swift'>Swift</option><option value = 'Logan'>Logan</option></select>);
const Sedan =() =>(<select><option value = 'Indigo'>Indigo</option><option value='Xuv'>Xuv</option><option value = 'Accent'>Accent</option></select>);
```

and your swith case should be like this:

```
 switch(ele){
    case 'hatchback':
          ReactDOM.render(<Hatch/>,val);
          break;
    case 'sedan':
          ReactDOM.render(<Sedan/>,val);
          break;
    case 'van':
          ReactDOM.render(van,val);
          break;
  }
```

please fine fiddle link working and tested copy for reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/67343/